# Optimize way of making query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a project in codeigniter. I am facing problem in making query on the basis of multiple condition. The simplest way is to make seperate condition for each property, but I need an optimized way cause I will have more than 25 properties later on, so 25 conditions look weired. 
Here is sample code

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('listings');
$this->db->join('hotel_features','listings.id = hotel_features.listing_id');
$this->db->where('listings.country_code',$country_t);
$this->db->like('listings.city',$city_t);


    if($room_features_ids != '')
    {
        $room_features_array[0] = "extra_beds";
        $room_features_array[1] = "satellite_tv";
        $room_features_array[2] = "airconditioning";
        $room_features_array[3] = "cable_tv_service";
        $room_features_array[4] = "bathroom";
        $room_features_array[5] = "phone";
        $room_features_array[6] = "wifi";
        $room_features_array[7] = "kitchen";
        $room_features_array[8] = "desk";
        $room_features_array[9] = "refrigerator";   

        $room_features_ids = explode("-",$room_features_ids);

                    // if $room_features_array has 0,1,2 this means first 3 features are available in hotel.
        foreach($room_features_ids as $ids)
        {
            if($room_features_array[$ids] == 'extra_beds')
            {
                $this->db->where('hotel_features.extra_beds',1);    
            }
            else if($room_features_array[$ids] == 'satellite_tv')
            {
                $this->db->where('hotel_features.satellite_tv',1);  
            }
            //and so on.... for all properties
        }
    }
```

Now my question is that, Is there any optimize way to do it?
Something like

```
        foreach($room_features_ids as $ids)
        {
            $this->db->where('hotel_features.'.$room_features_array[$ids],1);   
        }
```

Or any other way? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is 1 in your where clause as a parameter? is it static or dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

With 25 features, you're also looking at 25 columns. If the number of features is subject to change frequently, why not have a pair of `listing_id` and `feature` columns? That way, only the features that are present need to be inserted into the database.

Your `WHERE` query can be

```
foreach($room_features_ids as $ids)
    {
        $this->db->where('hotel_features.feature', $room_features_array[$ids]);
    }
```

where all the specified conditions have to be present. Of course, since you're now joining multiple rows from `hotel_features` to a single row in `listings`, you should aggregate the rows from `hotel_features`:

```
$this->db->group_by('listings.id);
```

Comment: No this is not join multiple hotel_features row. Its in one row with the column names like, extra_beds, wifi etc
I made them seperate columns for filters only. So i can filter on the basis of single feature

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('listings');
$this->db->join('hotel_features','listings.id = hotel_features.listing_id');
$this->db->where('listings.country_code',$country_t);
$this->db->like('listings.city',$city_t);
if($room_features_ids != '')
{
    $room_features_array[0] = "extra_beds";
    $room_features_array[1] = "satellite_tv";
    $room_features_array[2] = "airconditioning";
    $room_features_array[3] = "cable_tv_service";
    $room_features_array[4] = "bathroom";
    $room_features_array[5] = "phone";
    $room_features_array[6] = "wifi";
    $room_features_array[7] = "kitchen";
    $room_features_array[8] = "desk";
    $room_features_array[9] = "refrigerator";   

    $ids = explode("-",$room_features_ids);

    $counter    =   0;
    foreach($room_features_array as $key => $value){

        if($value == $room_features_array[$ids[$counter]]){
            $this->db->where("hotel_features.$value",1);    
        }
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: to increment ids index

Comment: Almost same way like i did with an extra if loop :P

Answer (score 1):

Use $this->db->where_in(); for checking multiple field contains single value or vice-versa

In your case,

```
$condn_arr = array('hotel_features.extra_beds','hotel_features.satellite_tv','hotel_features.airconditioning'); 
$this->db->where(1,$condn_arr);
```